# How do I create a transition between from Login View to Tab View in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Here's the snippet of code from `LoginView`:

```
Button(action: {
    if loginAndPasswordAreOK() {
        // Perform Segue to TabView
    } else {
        self.isValidLoginAndPassword = false
        self.email = ""
        self.password = ""
    }
}, label: {
```

and there's a piece of code of `MainTabView` (aka Home Tab):

```
struct MainTabView: View {
var body: some View {
    TabView {
        Text("Home Tab")
            .font(.system(size: 30, weight: .bold, design: .rounded))
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "house.fill")
                Text("Home")
            }
```

I googled around and saw `NavigationLink` or something but I don't want to wrap up this transition to a NavController at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
    import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var isPassOk: Bool = false
    var userPass: String = "1234"
    @State var userGivenPass: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        
        
        
        if isPassOk == false
        {
            HStack
            {
                
                
                
                TextField("Enter your Pass Here!", text: $userGivenPass)
                    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                
                
                Button("Log in") {
                    
                    // do your logig Here!
                    if userGivenPass == userPass
                    {
                        withAnimation(.easeInOut)
                        {
                            isPassOk = true
                        }
                        
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        isPassOk = false
                    }
                    
                    
                }
                
            }
            .font(Font.title)
            .padding()
        }
        else if isPassOk == true
        {
            TabView {
                Text("Home Tab")
                    .font(.system(size: 30, weight: .bold, design: .rounded))
                    .tabItem {
                        Image(systemName: "house.fill")
                        Text("Home")
                    }
                
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

**Here Updated for you:**

```
  import SwiftUI

    struct ContentView: View {
        
        @State var isPassOk: Bool = false
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        
        
        if isPassOk == false
        {
            LogInView(isPassOk: $isPassOk)
        }
        else if isPassOk == true
        {
            MainTabView()
        }
        
        
        
        
    }
}




struct LogInView: View {
    
    
    @Binding var isPassOk: Bool
    var userPass: String = "1234"
    @State var userGivenPass: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
  
        HStack
        {
  
            
            TextField("Enter your Pass Here!", text: $userGivenPass)
                .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
            
            
            Button("Log in") {
                
                // do your logig Here!
                if userGivenPass == userPass
                {
                    withAnimation(.easeInOut)
                    {
                        isPassOk = true
                    }
                    
                }
                else
                {
                    isPassOk = false
                }
   
            }
            
        }
        .font(Font.title)
        .padding()
        
    }
 
    
}







struct MainTabView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        
        TabView {
            Text("Home Tab")
                .font(.system(size: 30, weight: .bold, design: .rounded))
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "house.fill")
                    Text("Home")
                }
            
        }
        
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: Assuming that my tab view is declared in a separate file and is called `MainTabView`, can I inline it `else if isPassOk == true { MainTabView }`? The problem with that is I can see both `LoginView` and `MainTabView` but I'd like to perform a full transition instead (e.g., I don't want to see any elements from LoginView when I click on Log In.

Comment: defiantly! SwiftUI do not care what we want, it cares about what it wants! SwiftUI always and always ask a view for render, I am telling to SwiftUI render LogIN view until the pass is wrong, if the Pass is right, start render another view, which in our case is TabView, Yes to your Question you can do it

Comment: OK so the problem now is that if I do `else if isPassOk == true { MainTabView }` I can see both LoginView and MainTabView without logging in.